# Git branching efficient workflow

Tags: git, continuous-integration

Here's my company's release process. I just want to see if it could be optimized.

1. There are four branches,

- TeamA - All the changes done by Team A members go there. It is deployed to TeamA QA box.
- TeamB - All the changes done by Team B goes there. It is deployed to TeamB QA box.
- Release - The changes from TeamA & TeamB branch goes here. This gets deployed to UAT box.
- Main - Once the Release branch deployed to Production, it gets merged to main.

2. This is the typical dev workflow for a TeamA developer.

- create a Feature/Bug branch from TeamA & push the changes.
- It gets tested by QA team in QA box and get signed off.
- When the release time comes, developer creates another Feature/Bug branch from release branch & push the changes(manually). Because TeamA branch will have so many other changes.

As you can see, developer doing 'branching and pushing' two times on two different branches. Since, its manual step, there's no guarantee that developer pushing the same changes on both steps.

How can we avoid developer doing same steps twice?

Answer (score 0):

Scrap the TeamA and TeamB branches; they are worse than useless.

The idea of testing each change twice makes sense:

- The first time, you're testing in isolation, so you don't have to unpick merges if things go wrong.
- The second time, you're testing the combination that's going to be released, to make sure fixes don't interact badly.

In your workflow, both the TeamA and Release branches have combinations of changes, but they have *different* combinations. Any testing done on the TeamA branch is against a version of the code which is never going to be released. Any test failures at that point require reverting that change, and then re-testing a different combination of changes, which also won't be released.

So my advice would be to drop the TeamA and TeamB branches, and have QA check out individual task branches for the initial testing.

Comment: Thanks IMSoP. So, i understand from your point that there's no way to avoid this duplicated effort.  For small changes it's not a big deal. But, for big projects where you change tons of files, it will be a huge effort to do twice and it's error-prone.

Comment: @NepzSolutions It's obviously possible that I've missed an advantage you're getting out of the TeamA and TeamB branches, but I *think* you'll be better off having just the task branches (which can be tested individually in QA environments) and a single Release branch (which will be tested in UAT).